# n Rails 6, what's the proper way to add a decimal column to a table via a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, ruby-on-rails-6

I just upgraded to Rails 6.1.4.4 and a migration that previously passed in Rails 4 fails in the new set up.  It is

```
class AddLatLngToStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    add_column :stores, :lat, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
    add_column :stores, :lng, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
  end
end
```

Now I get the error when I run “rake db:migrate”

```
-- add_column(:stores, :lat, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
```

What’s the proper way to add a column in Rails 6?

Comment: Lose the brackets and hash rockets. Try `add_column :stores, :lat, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 6`

Answer (score 0):

Always good to reference the official docs, here's for the `add_column` method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column

If you want to stick to the hash syntax for some reason what you had should still work as long as you drop the curly braces.